# Google BigQuery query in Python works when using result(), but Permission issue when using to_dataframe()

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I've run into a problem after upgrades of my pip packages and my bigquery connector that returns query results suddenly stopped working with following error message

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('path/to/file', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
])

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)
data = client.query('select * from dataset.table').to_dataframe()
```

> PermissionDenied: 403 request failed: the user does not have
> bigquery.readsessions.create' permission

But! If you switched the code to

```
data = client.query('select * from dataset.table').result()
```

(dataframe -> result) you received the data in RowIterator format and were able to properly read them.

The same script using to_dataframe with the same credentials was working on the server. Therefore I set my bigquery package to the same version 2.28.0, which still did not help.

I could not find any advices on this error / topic anywhere, so I just want to share if any of you faced the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways of receiving data from bigquery. Using the [BQ Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage) is considered more efficient for larger result sets compared to the other options:

> The BigQuery Storage Read API provides a third option that represents an improvement over prior options. When you use the Storage Read API, structured data is sent over the wire in a binary serialization format. This allows for additional parallelism among multiple consumers for a set of results

The Python BQ library internally determines whether it can use the BQ Storage API or not. **For the result method, it uses the tradtional tabledata.list method internally, whereas the to_dataframe method uses the BQ Storage API if the according package is installed.**

However, **using the BQ Storage API requires you to have the bigquery.readSessionUser Role respectively the readsessions.create right which in your case seems to be lacking.**

By uninstalling the google-cloud-bigquery-storage, the google-cloud-bigquery package was falling back to the list method. Hence, by de-installing this package, you were working around the lack of rights.

See the [BQ Python Libary Documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.to_dataframe) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for additional explanation!  I thought there would be such issue, but I didn't have rights to update permissions for the service account, so I was looking for a workaround.. and I also knew it was working for me before without changing the permissions. In this case I only process small amount of data, so I believe google-cloud-bigquery is "enough". Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Just set
create_bqstorage_client=False

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os
client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = client.query(query)
df = query_job.result().to_dataframe(create_bqstorage_client=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Resolution**

Along with google-cloud-bigquery package, I also had installed package ***google-cloud-bigquery-storage***. Once I uninstalled that one using

```
pip uninstall google-cloud-bigquery-storage
```

everything started working again! Unfortunately, the error message was not so straightforward so it took some time to figure out :)