# BigQuery Permission error when using to_dataframe() as BigQuery Admin role

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm having a similar problem to the one stated in
[Google BigQuery query in Python works when using result(), but Permission issue when using to_dataframe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976543/google-bigquery-query-in-python-works-when-using-result-but-permission-issue)
in that .result() works fine but to_dataframe() throws an error, but my problem shouldn't be connected to lack of permissions if my role is BigQuery Admin. I also have a role Editor, could that perhaps obstruct the way permissions work?

Answer (score 2):

The answer turned out to be quite simple, though not obvious.
One should set `create_bqstorage_client` to `False`.

```
.to_dataframe(create_bqstorage_client=False)
```

As in the linked issue, the problem was in regards to bqstorage, however uninstalling `google-cloud-bigquery-storage` was not enough, as `_validate_bqstorage` function is checking both parameters and returns `False` only if both are either `None` or `False`.

```
using_bqstorage_api = bqstorage_client or create_bqstorage_client
if not using_bqstorage_api:
    return False
```

On the side note, I've created a custom function that takes virtually the same amount of time. If, for some reason, reader is still unable to use `.to_dataframe`, this function may be helpful

```
def sql_to_df(query):
    query_job = client.query(query) # API request
    results = query_job.result() # Waits for query to finish
    data = []
    for i, row in enumerate(results):
        if i==0:
            columns = list(row.keys())
        data.append(list(row.values()))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
    df.index += 1
    return df
```

[image]