# bigquery client query run to_dataframe() doesn't work in airflow composer in GCP and throws 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission Error

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to make the bigquery client query to dataframe run using the airflow composer in GCP. This works good in the local system without airflow.
Even in airflow, `client.query(query)` works good but not `client.query(query).to_dataframe()`
and I can't understand why, if it was a permission issue then `client.query(query)` this shouldn't have worked too.
I've tried giving all the possible permissions and I don't think its a permissions issue.

Below the code which works locally and but not on airflow in gcp,

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project="GCP PROJECT NAME")


#get Brand image score for all interview IDs
query="""SELECT * from Table LIMIT 10"""

df_bi=client.query(query).to_dataframe()

print("Success")
```

**expected results:**
Success

**Actual result**

```
[2023-04-20, 12:47:25 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1853} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "request failed: the user does not have 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission for 'projects/projectname'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try first fetching the results by using the [result](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest#perform-a-query)() method from the client and then converting it into a dataframe?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project="GCP PROJECT NAME")

query = """
    SELECT * from Table LIMIT 10
"""

table = client.query(query).result()
df = table.to_dataframe()
print(df)
```

Comment: I found another thread which had the same issue, it had the solution you've provided and it worked. Tagging that here
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976543/google-bigquery-query-in-python-works-when-using-result-but-permission-issue)

Thanks for the solution, this works!